# Is there a more essential solution to this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, alternative-proof

$f(x),g(x):[0,1]\to [0,1]$,Prove that:$$\int_0^1f(g(x))dx\leqslant \int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_0^1g(x)dx$$
The solution uses $F(x)=f(x)-x$ and turns the problem into:$$\int_0^1F(g(x))dx\leqslant \frac12$$
Is there more obvious or essential approach?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276722/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4033497/42969

Comment: In Martin R.'s link, the statement is proved for $f$ monotone increasing, and indeed, the statement is not necessarily true if $f$ does not satisfy this condition. Continuity conditions on $f,g$ may also be necessary.

Comment: $g \equiv 0$, $f(x)=1_{\{0\}}(x)$.